# how to make command for specific role on discord.py

Tags: python, command, discord.py, roles

I Want to check if the message author has admin role to use this command or not
in my case it always gives me False and i know the code is not right

```
 @client.command(pass_content=True)
    async def new(ctx, member:discord.Member, nick):
        role = author.get_role(name="Admin")
        if role in author.roles:
            await member.edit(nick=nick)
            await ctx.send(f"Nickname changed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@commands.has_role(role ID or name)`

For a role ID:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(123123)
async def test(ctx):
   await ctx.send('It works!')
```

For a role name:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("role_name")
async def test(ctx):
   await ctx.send('It works!')
```

I highly recommend using a role id because role names aren't unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@commands.has_role("rolename")` the in your `@client.command`

like this

```
@client.command(pass_content=True)
@commands.has_role("mod")
async def name(parameters):
   #your code
```